# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 on Xcode using a static library

Tags: xcode

I'm beginner on IOS developing. I try to build an application that contain a swift and Objective C languages. In the application i use library named `libjjeromq.a` witch I have compiled using this command:

```
ar -rv libjjermoq.a [liste of files.o]
```

- I have add the library to the Linker Library. I have add the library search path too.
- I have added the flags -ObjC
- I have added all the files .m to Compile file sources
- I have configured the header search paths
- I have test the `libjjeromq.a` library and it's able to work on x86_64 architecture.

But when I built I get errors like this:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_IOSArray_throwOutOfBoundsWithMsg", referenced from:
      _OrgZeromqZMQ_pollWithOrgZeromqZMQ_PollItemArray_withInt_withLong_ in ZMQ.o
      -[OrgZeromqZMQ_Poller unregisterWithOrgZeromqZMQ_Socket:] in ZMQ.o
      _OrgZeromqZMQ_Poller_removeWithInt_ in ZMQ.o
      -[OrgZeromqZMQ_Poller unregisterWithJavaNioChannelsSelectableChannel:] in ZMQ.o
      -[OrgZeromqZMQ_Poller getItemWithInt:] in ZMQ.o
      -[OrgZeromqZMQ_Poller getSocketWithInt:] in ZMQ.o
      -[OrgZeromqZMQ_Poller pollWithLong:] in ZMQ.o
      ...
  "_IOSClass_class_", referenced from:
      _ZmqStreamEngine_new_decoderWithInt_withLong_withZmqSessionBase_withInt_ in StreamEngine.o
      _ZmqStreamEngine_new_encoderWithInt_withZmqSessionBase_withInt_ in StreamEngine.o
      _ZmqStreamEngine_new_decoderWithInt_withLong_withZmqSessionBase_withInt_ in libjjermoq.a(StreamEngine.o)
      _ZmqStreamEngine_new_encoderWithInt_withZmqSessionBase_withInt_ in libjjermoq.a(StreamEngine.o)
  "_IOSClass_forNameWithNSString_", referenced from:
      -[ZmqOptions setsockoptWithInt:withId:] in Options.o
      -[ZmqOptions setsockoptWithInt:withId:] in libjjermoq.a(Options.o)
  "_IOSClass_fromClass", referenced from:
      ___OrgZeromqZMQ_class__block_invoke in ZMQ.o
      ___OrgZeromqZMQ_Context_class__block_invoke in ZMQ.o
      ___OrgZeromqZMQ_Socket_class__block_invoke in ZMQ.o
      ___OrgZeromqZMQ_Poller_class__block_invoke in ZMQ.o
      ___OrgZeromqZMQ_PollItem_class__block_invoke in ZMQ.o
      ___OrgZeromqZMQ_ErrorEnum_class__block_invoke in ZMQ.o
      ___OrgZeromqZMQ_Event_class__block_invoke in ZMQ.o
      ...
  "_IOSClass_fromProtocol", referenced from:
      ___OrgZeromqZLoop_IZLoopHandler_class__block_invoke in ZLoop.o
      ___OrgZeromqZThread_IAttachedRunnable_class__block_invoke in ZThread.o
      ___OrgZeromqZThread_IDetachedRunnable_class__block_invoke in ZThread.o
      ___ZmqAddress_IZAddress_class__block_invoke in Address.o
      ___ZmqIDecoder_class__block_invoke in IDecoder.o
      ___ZmqIEncoder_class__block_invoke in IEncoder.o
      ___ZmqIEngine_class__block_invoke in IEngine.o
      ...
  "_IOSObjectArray_Set", referenced from:
      _OrgZeromqZMQ_pollWithOrgZeromqZMQ_PollItemArray_withInt_withLong_ in ZMQ.o
      _OrgZeromqZMQ_Poller_insertWithOrgZeromqZMQ_PollItem_ in ZMQ.o
      _OrgZeromqZMQ_Poller_removeWithInt_ in ZMQ.o
      -[OrgZeromqZMQ_Poller pollWithLong:] in ZMQ.o
      _OrgZeromqZLoop_rebuild in ZLoop.o
      -[ZmqCtx create_socketWithInt:] in Ctx.o
      -[ZmqCtx destroy_socketWithZmqSocketBase:] in Ctx.o
      ...
  "_IOSObjectArray_SetAndConsume", referenced from:
      _ZmqMtrie_add_helperWithByteArray_withInt_withZmqPipe_ in Mtrie.o
      _ZmqPipe_pipepairWithZmqZObjectArray_withZmqPipeArray_withIntArray_withBooleanArray_ in Pipe.o
      _ZmqProxy_proxyWithZmqSocketBase_withZmqSocketBase_withZmqSocketBase_ in Proxy.o
      -[ZmqTrie addWithByteArray:withInt:] in Trie.o
      _ZmqMtrie_add_helperWithByteArray_withInt_withZmqPipe_ in libjjermoq.a(Mtrie.o)
      _ZmqPipe_pipepairWithZmqZObjectArray_withZmqPipeArray_withIntArray_withBooleanArray_ in libjjermoq.a(Pipe.o)
      _ZmqProxy_proxyWithZmqSocketBase_withZmqSocketBase_withZmqSocketBase_ in libjjermoq.a(Proxy.o)
      ...
```

Please can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that there is two differents files situated in two differents repertoires but they have the same name ! the files were : org/zeromq/zmq.o and zmq/zmq.o.

The process to create the library : `ar -rv libjjermoq.a [liste of files.o]` select randomly the first zmq.o that it find and ignores the other one ! As result the methodes witch are defined in the missed zmq.o will not be found in the result library .a.

The sollution is to rename one of the files and avoid in all cases to have 2 or more files with the same name even if they are in different repertoires !